Opening SQL in CLI for MERN STACK development
I am a beginner learning MERN stack , I have been facing problem regarding running the sql n CLI . I have navigated to bin folder too , still no response
I tried navigating through bin folder
error is prompting that
PS C:\> cd Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin mysql -u root -p
Set-Location : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'p' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Path 
-PassThru -PipelineVariable -LiteralPath.
At line:1 char:58
+ cd Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin mysql -u root -p
+                                                          ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand


Run these 2 commands separately.

And you are in the mysql shell folder, not in the mysql folder. But not sure how this is related to programming... And I thought M in MERN sttood for MongoDB, not mysql...

Does this answer your question? MySQL command line client for Windows
